# Enabling an Android app button from within a function

Tags: java, android, button

I am making an android app, where, during startup I disable the pauze button of the media player. After the ok button is clicked (and music starts to play), I want to enable the pauze button.

This code works fine, except for the last line (I did delete some non-relevant lines). That gives me a runtime error (NullPointerException).

I used MainActivity.this to access the button. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // initialise variables
    TextView textOut;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Button buttonPauze;
    Button ok;

    // *******************************************************
    // set Layout - on create
    // *******************************************************
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        // *******************************************************
        // set the play, generate and pauze buttons
        // *******************************************************
        Button buttonPauze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPauze);
        Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);

        buttonPauze.setOnClickListener(buttonPauseOnClickListener);
    buttonPauze.setEnabled(false);
    ok.setEnabled(true);

    // *******************************************************
    // on click generate
    // *******************************************************
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MainActivity.this.buttonPauze.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
Button buttonPauze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPauze);
```

with:

```
buttonPauze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPauze);
```

---

Basically, you had 2 `buttonPauze`'s, one as local variable and the other as a class field. By removing the `Button`, you are using the class field `buttonPauze` locally and assign a proper object to it.

---

Same thing with `ok`!

Comment: Oh my, of course! This error creeped in when I put them as global variables. Thanks for pointing it out! A fresh view always helps!

Answer (score 2):

NPE is because you are assigning button reference to local variable in `onCreate()` and then try to access global one which is not initialized. Replace this:

```
Button buttonPauze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPauze);
```

with this

```
buttonPauze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPauze);
```

To avoid mistakes like this you may adapt common practice and prefix class global variables, like

```
Button mButton;
```

Do not use `MainActivity.this.` syntax. It is pointless as you are accessing variable of the same class. Just

```
buttonPauze.setEnabled(true);
```

suffices (BTW: it is "pause").

Comment: Thanks! I experimented with MainActivity.this, because it didn't work. Thanks for the pauSe tip. Confusion came from Dutch :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
Button buttonPauze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPauze);
```

You're defining and assigning to a local variable, not the instance variable. Therefore when you reference the instance variable in the line

```
MainActivity.this.buttonPauze.setEnabled(true);
```

`buttonPauze` has not been set and it's still `null`. To fix, simply change to

```
buttonPauze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPauze);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating the local variable with the same name of global variable, its giving problem.

// do not create local variables

```
  buttonPauze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPauze);
  ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't define buttonPause two times..